# How to return a different column instead of the criteria column in MySql? query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. I want to return the TITLES of the programs with 1 or more interdependence. I'm able to return the IDs of the programs by intersection but unsure how to revise my SQL statement to return the names only. Essentially, I want to vlookup using program_ID and see if it matches with project_ID. If there is a match, I want to return title for that project_ID.

```
SELECT DISTINCT program_ID
FROM PROJECTS
WHERE program_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT project_ID FROM INTERDEPENDENCE);
```

PROJECTS

| title | project_ID | program_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 2 |
| DEF | 2 | NULL |
| GHI | 3 | 2 |
| JKL | 4 | 1 |

INTERDEPENDENCE

| interdependence_ID | name | project_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | aaa | 1 |
| 11 | bbb | 2 |

Edit: I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Do a `JOIN` instead of `IN`:

```
create table PROJECTS(
title varchar(50),project_ID int,program_ID int);
insert into PROJECTS VALUES
('ABC', 1,2),
('DEF', 2,NULL),
('GHI', 3,2),
('JKL', 4,1);

create table
INTERDEPENDENCE(
interdependence_ID int, name varchar(50),project_ID int);

insert into INTERDEPENDENCE values
(10,'aaa',1),
(11,'bbb',2);

SELECT DISTINCT program_ID, name
FROM PROJECTS JOIN
 (SELECT DISTINCT project_ID, name FROM INTERDEPENDENCE) I
 ON program_ID=I.project_ID;
```

[Here's a demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=865dd30dc82c9d87cf9921e2591bc33a)